# android UI implementation Opinion

Tags: java, android, tabs

I i've a layout with 4 tabs at bottom a menu bar at the top and the all content it's to display in the center of the screen, and the tabs and menu bar is visible in all screens. In some screens I want to have some buttons to open another page (different of the tabs content) but in the center of the screen as the others.

I tried to implement that with tabhost (4 tabs), one activity per tab, but then I was in random tab and i've per example a button to show me another activity i want it to show in the center of the ecran without losing the menu bar and tab bar.

So, the best way to do this is with tabHost and a activity per tab like I did and try to find a solution for this, or just implement this using fragments?

Thanks

Comment: So you have a layout with a header and footer and you want to switch out the center part to different screens?  Sounds like a definition of what fragments are for.

Comment: Fragments. Forget the old tab host pattern. Also you might want to look into the action bar and it's split when narrow option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the activity for each tab, use fragment for each tabhost.

Please refer the below link

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html